# What is a difference between DeleteObject() and Recycle() methods for SP.Folder

Tags: sharepoint, directory, recycle, sharepoint-clientobject

Could anybody help me to understand a difference between DeleteObject() and Recycle() methods for SP.Folder?

I found this documentation, but it's not clear for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.recycle.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Delete()
```

delete permanently without using the recycle bin.

to move item to recycle bin use

```
Recycle();
```

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/spfolder-splist-deleting-versus-recycling/

Comment: Thank you! I missed, that SharePoint has a recycle bin on a Site Settings page. That is a gr8 feature!

Comment: It was not obvious for me, but after some investigation I found that after just `List.Recycle();` llist is not being deleted. Instead, `ClientContext.Web.Context.HasPendingRequest` becomes `true` and you need to call `ClientContext.Web.Context.ExecuteQuery();` finally to execute the recycle query.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint maintains a recycle bin like a windows OS, that we can use it through our code for temporary deletion. I used Recycle() in one of our project. When we use Delete() or DeleteObject() it deletes the item directly without putting them in recycle bin but if you use Recycle() method it will send the item in recycle bin.

Shiv Tomar

Shiv.Tomar@tekritisoftware.com

http://www.tekritisoftware.com/brochure/Microsoft-Sharepoint-Development